# How to block for loop till sqlite query get executed?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt4

I am writing program in Qt and below is one portion of my code:

```
for(int row=0; row < 15; row++)
    {
        for(int column=0; column < 12; column++ )
        {
            if(query->exec(db->getInsertQuery(row,column)))
            {

            }else
                qDebug() << "Failed to insert cell";
        }
    }
```

When I run this program it gets into "Not responding" state. When I am running

```
    query->exec(db->getInsertQuery(0,0));
    query->exec(db->getInsertQuery(0,1));
    ....
```

in place of for loop program runs properly but I cant write so many lines in my program. Can you please suggest me way to block for loop till query get executed and How can I show progress bar in some box till for loop completes?

Comment: You can use [QProgressDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qprogressdialog.html#details) to show progress bar during many synchronous operations and to avoid non-responding state. See the documentation page for an example.

Comment: The key point is that you *must return to the event loop*. A modal  `QProgressDialog` will call `processEvents()` for you (see its docs); otherwise you need to somehow allow event processing. See also [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects).

Comment: @peppe I solved this issue by putting query->finish() below if-else and my program works Greatly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QtSql, I assume you should use `execBatch()` method for this kind of tasks

[Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html#execBatch)

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.prepare("insert into myTable values (?, ?)");

QVariantList ints;
ints << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4;
q.addBindValue(ints);

QVariantList names;
names << "Harald" << "Boris" << "Trond" << QVariant(QVariant::String);
q.addBindValue(names);

if (!q.execBatch())
    qDebug() << q.lastError();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop the execution of your query and use the combination of QProgressDialog and qApp->processEvents() calls.

Basically you do the following:

```
// Run queries with numbers 0-99
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
     // run your query

     // update the progress dialog value

     // Run the Qt event loop to handle the GUI updates and avoid the "not responsing" app state
     qApp->processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents );
}
```

You may take a look at my video generator class: https://sourceforge.net/p/karlyriceditor/code/HEAD/tree/src/videogenerator.cpp - check the generate() function, it does very similar to what you need, generating the video file and updating the progress dialog while doing that.